# ANGULAR isn't sending headers to my particular Http Post Request

Tags: angular, http-headers, authorization, jwt

here is a function for sending http post request to my server

```
 likePost(post){
    let head = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Authorization":"JWT "+localStorage.getItem("token")
  });
  let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: head});
  this.http.post(this.likeurl+post.id+'/like',requestOptions)
    .subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log(response);
});
}
```

but when ever i fire this fucntion i'm getting a 403 forbidden request from server saying you are not authenticated

this issue is too funny because all of my crud operations are working absolutely fine with same headers sent to server
but this function is unable to make request to server

here is my post requst for creating an object in server

```
 createPost(input:HTMLInputElement){
    // input.value='';
    let post={content:input.value};
  let head = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  "Authorization":"JWT "+localStorage.getItem("token")

});
  let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: head});
    let body = JSON.stringify(post);

    this.http.post(this.url,body,requestOptions)
      .subscribe(response =>{
        post['id']=response.json().id;
        this.posts.splice(0,0,post);


      });
}
```

in that way all the crud operation are perfectly in sync with my authorization headers but this like function isn't 
i dont understand what the issue is and how it can be solved 
tried to observe if i coded something wrong but everything seems to be good

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check:

- Make sure that the token has value on that specific state
- Verify that specific API if it is really catching that token

One thing to consider as well, you should be doing this by using [Angular Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

You are duplicating codes here, adding headers on every http request method you will do.
[This](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) should help you do that.

Comment: token has the value and i checked it using postman  which i can conclude that i can make valid requests with that token and i have also mentioned that all other crud views are working perfectly fine with the same token and there is no issue in that and i have tried angular interoceptor but it makes no sense when every crud operation is working perfectly fine with those headers then this function should also work the same